# constraint c for table t does not exist on PostgreSQL even though it's there

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run an INSERT query on **TablePlus**.

```
INSERT INTO minutes_clone (date, ticker, "lastTime", "openTime", date_time, group_type, "totalVolume", "totalPrice", "totalTrades")
        VALUES('2021-07-02', 'YELP', '00:15:00', '00:00:00', '2021-07-02 00:00:00', 15,  0,  0,  0) 
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT minutes_clone_stick_tickers_unique 
        DO UPDATE SET "lastTime" = '00:15:00', "openTime" = '00:00:00', date_time = '2021-07-02 00:00:00', "totalVolume" = 0, "totalPrice" = 0, "totalTrades" = 0
        RETURNING id;
```

Instead of the query sending a success message, I'm getting an
ERROR:  constraint "minutes_clone_stick_tickers_unique" for table "minutes_clone" does not exist.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deucH.png) is an image of my table structure.

to replicate:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."minutes_clone" (
    "ticker" varchar NOT NULL,
    "totalTrades" int4 NOT NULL,
    "totalPrice" numeric NOT NULL,
    "totalVolume" int4,
    "lastTime" time NOT NULL,
    "openTime" time NOT NULL,
    "date" date NOT NULL,
    "group_type" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "date_time" timestamp,
    "parent_id" int4,
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass),
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE INDEX "minutes_clone_ticker_group_date_index" ON "public"."minutes_clone" USING BTREE ("ticker","group_type","date_time");

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "minutes_clone_stick_tickers_unique" ON "public"."minutes_clone" USING BTREE ("date","ticker","openTime","group_type");

CREATE INDEX "minutes_clone_date_time_index" ON "public"."minutes_clone" USING BTREE ("date_time");
```

I've tried many things, like removing **ON CONSTRAINT** and dropping and re-adding the constraing but haven't been able to solve this issue. Any solutions?

Comment: Don't post images. Post the `CREATE TABLE` statements, including all applicable constraints, as text that can be executed, so that the `INSERT` can be executed to produce the behavior you don't understand.

Comment: Best guess is you are not inserting on the table you think you are. Either a case issue for the table name that needs to be quoted or a schema issue where the table with the constraint comes later then one without.

Comment: I've added  ```CREATE``` statements so you can replicate the table

Comment: That's a little odd, but PG doesn't consider that a constraint. At least it's not in `pg_constraint`.  But it can be found in `pg_index, pg_class`.

Comment: See this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=67f3047d3cb0e8523ae95f95c29cea46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up indexes and constraints.  That is understandable, because a unique constraint is always implemented by a unique index, but they are still not the same.

To make your statement work, you need a unique constraint on top of the index you currently have.  You can create that with:

```
ALTER TABLE public.minutes_clone
   ADD UNIQUE USING INDEX minutes_clone_stick_tickers_unique;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem is now solved. Should I do this query for all unique constraints I have?

Comment: It is up to you. I like to have constraints, because they are SQL standard, but it doesn't really matter.